# Outsystems - tab issue

Tags: tabs, outsystems

I am developing an application using Outsystems, where-in I am using 'RichWidgets\Tabs_ClientSide'. I need to navigate from one page to other page, where the other page has multiple tabs. Currently, I am being redirected to the first tab by default.

Is there some property or functionality so that I can navigate the control to a particular tab(web-block) at runtime ?

Thanks !

I have implemented the below given answer.
I have a link. When I click that link it is redirected to destination A. I have an input paramater which is a boolean parameter. I pass 'true' as its value. The destination A which is a webscreen has a webblock B. On that particular webblock, for the InitialActiveTab property I have checked whether the input parameter is True or False.
For true I am passing WebblockC.Id as the value.

But, on the browser underneth the webblock it is showing this error.

Invalid use of RichWidgets\Tabs_ClientSide: The initial tab must have the 'title' extended property defined.

I have set the OnTabActivation property as desired to the system, but still it does not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior can be accomplished this way:

- add an optional input parameter to the webscreens where you have the tabs to specify which tab to be selected when the user lands on the page
- feed that parameter to the `InitialactiveTab` input of the *Tabs_ClientSide* web block
- in all links where you want the target to open with an initial different tab, specify which tab to open by filling the optional input parameter you created with the title of the tab to be activated